# Listview rows order changes randomly on scroll of listview in android

Tags: android, listview

I have one ListView and one BaseAdapter.I am downloading Products from webservice and display on listview.It displays properly on listview.

But when I scroll ListView displays rows in random position means sometimes third row display in first position, middle position row display on last position and so on.

**This is my adapter class**

```
public class ProductListAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener{

    LayoutInflater inflater;
    ArrayList<Product> arrProducts;
    Context c;

    public ProductListAdapter(Context c, ArrayList<Product> arrProducts) {
        super();
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
        this.arrProducts = arrProducts;
        this.c = c;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return arrProducts.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return arrProducts.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        Product product = null;
        if(v == null) {
            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_listview_row, null);
            product = (Product) getItem(position);
            v.setTag(product);
        }else {
            product = (Product)v.getTag();
        }

        v.setOnClickListener(this);

        TextView tvProductname = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvProductname);
        tvProductname.setText(product.getTitle());

        String strReviewCount = product.getReviews();
        TextView tvReviewsCounts = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvReviews);
        if(strReviewCount != null) tvReviewsCounts.setText(strReviewCount +" Reviews");

        Button btnPrice = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPrice);
        btnPrice.setText(product.getSellingPrice());

        return v;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Product product = (Product) v.getTag();
        Intent i = new Intent(c, ProductDetails.class);
        i.putExtra(Product.PROD_ID, product.getId());
        startActivity(i);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        return super.getItemViewType(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getViewTypeCount() {
        return super.getViewTypeCount();
    }
}
```

**This is ListView on XML layout**

```
<ListView android:id="@+id/lstProducts" style="@style/fill_parent"
        android:dividerHeight="1dp" android:divider="#dbd3c5"
        android:scrollbars="vertical" android:layout_below="@id/layLine"></ListView>
```

**Also when I change `getView()` method of BaseAdapter like this it is working fine**

```
@Override
    public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {
        Product product = null;
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_listview_row, null);
        product = (Product) getItem(position);
        v.setTag(product);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);

        TextView tvProductname = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvProductname);
        tvProductname.setText(product.getTitle());

        String strReviewCount = product.getReviews();
        TextView tvReviewsCounts = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvReviews);
        if(strReviewCount != null) tvReviewsCounts.setText(strReviewCount +" Reviews");

        Button btnPrice = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPrice);
        btnPrice.setText(product.getSellingPrice());

        return v;
    }
```

But problem in this type is I am displaying image of product on listview row which I had not consider here.By using this type of code **`getView()` method always create new View when ever scroll of listView** so that I have to download image again and again.I used `ImageLoader` class which is using `cash memory` for download images but problem is that when I set image to ImageView many times it giving me `out of memory error`.

Please help me out from this problem.

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I landed here because of a link to the *right* solution.

The problem here is that you bind your product once to the view when you create a new view.   You should call this on every call of `getView`:

```
product = (Product) getItem(position);
v.setTag(product);
```

But you could call `v.setOnClickListener(this)` once you create the view (it won't change anyway).

This should do the trick. The view type implementation is just misused here. I recommend to read [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list-v/7739006#7739006)...

Comment: I know my answer was not the exact way to be used but for temporary purpose I managed it using view type. Hope your solution works and gets checked.

Comment: Thank you. I hope you don't feel offended, that wasn't my intention. The problem here was that people accept the *trick* as normal and working and then get really confused when things go wrong later or they want to use a real view type implementation... I just wanted it to be clear, instead starting rumors ;-)

Comment: No no, its good for me too to get the exact solution. Personally I think that your answer will surely work and I will also try it out. And feeling bad is never a case, I am also here to learn. This is got something new from you. Thanks.

Comment: Also, a very good article on Adapters: http://www.piwai.info/android-adapter-good-practices/

Answer (score 5):

Therefore, according to the [recommendations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7738527/getting-an-issue-while-checking-the-dynamically-generated-checkbox-through-list/7739006#7739006) made by [Knickedi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/920511/knickedi), the `getView()` method should look like:

```
public View getView(int position, View v, ViewGroup parent) {

    TextView tvProductname;
    TextView tvReviewsCounts;
    Button btnPrice;

    // Phase 1...
    if (v == null) {
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_listview_row, null);
        v.setOnClickListener(this);

        tvProductname = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvProductname);
        tvReviewsCounts = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.tvReviews);
        btnPrice = (Button)v.findViewById(R.id.btnPrice);

        v.setTag(R.id.tvProductname, tvProductname);
        v.setTag(R.id.tvReviews, tvReviewsCounts);
        v.setTag(R.id.btnPrice, btnPrice);
    }
    else {
        tvProductname = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.tvProductname);
        tvReviewsCounts = (TextView) v.getTag(R.id.tvReviews);
        btnPrice = (Button) v.getTag(R.id.btnPrice);   
    }

    // Phase 2...
    Product product = (Product) getItem(position);

    tvProductname.setText(product.getTitle());
    btnPrice.setText(product.getSellingPrice());

    String strReviewCount = product.getReviews();
    if(strReviewCount != null)
        tvReviewsCounts.setText(strReviewCount +" Reviews");

    return v;
}
```

Comment: Be carefull `public void setTag(int key, Object tag)` has been added in API Level 4...