# how to make a button get invisible in listview of an android app

Tags: android, listview, button, invisible

in my app i have a list view. Each list consists of a image, text and three buttons. 
I have placed all this in a ListActivity.

When the user clicks a particular button i use to call the download function of my app. At that time i want that button to be get invisibled. Following is the part of my code

```
public class Content extends ListActivity 
{
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        adapter = new EventAdapter(this);
        setListAdapter(adapter);
    }

  public class InventoryAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements OnClickListener
{        
    private Context context;   
    ImageButton b1;
    public InventoryAdapter(Context ctx) 
    {     
        context = ctx;
    }
    public long getItemId(int position) 
    {
        return position;
    }
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view;
        if(convertView == null) 
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)
            context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list, null);
            b1 = (ImageButton)view.findViewById(R.id.Btn1);
            b1.setOnClickListener(this);
        }
        else 
        {
            view = convertView;
        }
        b1.setTag(position);            
        return view;
   }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Log.e("onclick","onclick");
        Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.Btn1:
                selected_url=url[position];
                new DownloadTask1().execute();
            break;  
        }
    }
}
```

How to make the a particular button to get invisibled when the a position is clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create an array storing the list of clicks over the button according to their position.

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> list_Btn    = new ArrayList<Integer>(); //to make the buy button either visible or invisible
```

In the onclick of the button in list view to be as follows

```
request_holder.button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) 
                {
                                   Appconstant.list_Btn.add(position,View.INVISIBLE);       
                }
            });
            return convertView;
```

Then in the show list data of list view to be as follows

```
public void ListData(listViewHolder viewHolder, int position) 
        {
                if(Appconstant.list_Btn.get(position) == View.VISIBLE)
                {
                    request_holder.buy.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
                else if(Appconstant.list_Btn.get(position)== View.INVISIBLE)
                {
                    request_holder.buy.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

Use `button.setVisibility(View.Invisible);` for making your button invisible (The space occupied by the button remains as it is).

OR use `button.setVisibility(View.GONE);` (This removes the button from the layout and other views takes up the space)

So your `onClick` method will look like :

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        Log.e("onclick","onclick");
        Integer position = (Integer) v.getTag();
        switch(v.getId())
        {
            case R.id.Btn1:
                selected_url=url[position];
                btn1.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);   
                new DownloadTask1().execute();
            break;  
        }
    }
```

When you want to make them visible you have to use `View.VISIBLE`.

So you have to do like : `button.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);`

Comment: what you said is rite, but how to invisible the button in particular position in a listview....

Comment: i want the btn1 to get invisible of its own, according to the position it get clicked

Comment: i have used both the view.GONE and view.INVISIBLE, i have a list of 21 buttons. When i click on button at position 0, the buttons at position 5, 12, 20 are getting invisible or gone. i want to know "how to mention that button at position 0 to get invisible?"

Comment: Try with this : `((ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.btn1)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);` ?

Comment: Try using this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7551068/listview-rows-order-changes-randomly-on-scroll-of-listview-in-android/7551084#7551084 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5300962/getviewtypecount-and-getitemviewtype-methods-of-arrayadapter

Comment: @Karthik - thanx for all ur answers, i have already taken the position which i am clicking and i am seeing it in my logcat, my question is how to set the position number for the button to get invisible

Answer (score 0):

@Kartik this worked ((ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.btn1)).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE); thanks.